# How to compute the projection $P(v)$ of a vector to a subspace? How to find the matrix of $P$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P(v):  \mathbb{R^4} \to\mathbb{R^4}$ be the projection of a vector $v$ to the  space $\left\langle\left|\begin{smallmatrix}
1 \\ 
2\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{smallmatrix}\right|, \left|\begin{smallmatrix}
-1\\ 
\;\;2\\ 
-2\\ 
\;\;1
\end{smallmatrix}\right|\right\rangle$.

Compute $P(v)$ and corresponding matrix in standard bases.

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Compute"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment and also editing my post.
Sorry if it consider rude,It's not a homework but an exam question and write it here word by word :)

Comment: Unless you an adjective such as "orthogonal", one cannot speak of _the_ projection:  there are many projections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to find an orthonormal basis $(e_1,e_2)$ of the subspace onto which you want to project. This can by done by applying [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the vectors that span your subspace.

Once you have that
$$
P(v)=(v,e_1)e_1+(v,e_2)e_2.
$$

To get the matrix of $P$ in the canonical/standard basis $(f_1,\ldots,f_4)$, compute the coordinates of $P(f_j)$ in this basis. This is the $j$th column.